# Perl's Modules lists

Tags: perl, perl-module

I got confused with something while importing a module, like:

```
use POSIX;
```

&

```
use POSIX();
```

&

```
use POSIX qw(WNOHANG);
```

What is the difference between these `use`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Most modules use the `Exporter` module to expose functions/variables/constants in the callee's namespace.

```
use POSIX;
```

This will only import all symbols from POSIX's `@EXPORT` into the namespace of the calling module.

```
use POSIX();
```

This will *not import any symbols* into the calling namespace. It does however load the module, which means you can call functions like `POSIX::strftime(...)`, etc.

```
use POSIX(WNOHANG)
```

This will only import the symbol `WNOHANG` into the calling module's namespace.

If you are not familiar with the `@EXPORT` and `@EXPORT_OK` arrays, you should definitely run through the documentation of [Exporter](http://search.cpan.org/~toddr/Exporter-5.68/lib/Exporter.pm). Using `Exporter` is the standard way in Perl to export symbols from one module into the namespace of your module (the calling namespace). `POSIX` uses it as well.

It's also probably worth mentioning that modules designed with an object-oriented interface, generally do not require symbols to be imported.